# How to fix Neo4j inconsistencies?

Tags: neo4j

I was suffering some strange query errors when querying the relationships of a certain node and searching for the cause of them, I found a relationship that is in an strange state. If I try to delete it, I get the following error:

```
InvalidRecordException
Position[12400314] requested for high id[12400312], store is ok[true] recovery[false]
```

Then, I figured out how to use the ConsistencyCheckTool and the report stated that there are two conflicts:

```
2013-07-25 15:31:59.330+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The source node is not in use.
    Relationship[20037832,used=true,source=12400314,target=1502617,type=9,sPrev=20037834,sNext=-1,tPrev=-1,tNext=20024878,prop=-1]
    Inconsistent with: Node[12400314,used=false,rel=-1,prop=-1]
2013-07-25 15:31:59.330+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: ERROR: The target node is not in use.
    Relationship[20037834,used=true,source=315756,target=12400314,type=3,sPrev=-1,sNext=4566930,tPrev=-1,tNext=20037832,prop=-1]
    Inconsistent with: Node[12400314,used=false,rel=-1,prop=-1]
```

The first relationship does not exist and the second is the one I cannot delete.

Is there any way to solve this kind of inconsistencies? I don't mind losing data, I can recreate all the graph for a given user, but first I need to delete all the relationships and the node to create it again.

Comment: What neo4j version? Any chance to get over a copy of that store for investigation?

Comment: The problem ocurrs in 1.9.0 and 1.9.2. Sorry, but I'm not allowed to send you the data as it contain't sensitive information.

Comment: Ok, in order to get an NDA into place, please contact sales@neotechnology.com. Otherwise, maybe you can recreate it with a clean store?